# Express not serving static images

Tags: node.js, express

Attempting to use express to serve static assets (css, images, js) for the index.html view.

In app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
<img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
```

Folder structure

```
public
  css
    style.css
  images
    logo.jpg
  js
    app.js
```

All three required files seem to be served just fine, as they all have a 200 response status however the logo.jpg is not being rendered.

[image]
[image]

EDIT: The app.js in the public folder is not the script used to start the server.

FULL app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const index = require('./routes/index');
const install = require('./routes/install');
const webhook = require('./routes/webhooks');

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/install', install);
app.use('/webhook', webhook);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000, () => console.log('App running'));
```

Full Folder structure

```
public
  css
    style.css
  images
    logo.jpg
  js
    app.js
routes
  index
    index.js
  install
   index.js
  webhooks
   index.js
views
  app
   index.html
  error.html
app.js
```

Comment: drop the "/" in front of images and try again

Comment: <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"/>   still doesn't work

Comment: show the script being used to start app.js ( package.json  or nodemon or what ever

Comment: looks like directory and path issue. where the server js file located in the same folder as public?

Comment: The app.js in the public folder is not the script used to start the server. I realized that may have been confusing, just made an edit.

Comment: try with `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));` with the slash before public.... any thing better ?

Comment: Still get the same result with the /